# Ruby Motion how do I change back button's default color?

Tags: ios, ruby, rubymotion

Is there a way to change the default back button's color blue to my own specified color without having to set it as an image? I want to implement this using Ruby Motion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do that would be inside your view controller's `viewDidLoad` method, where you would chance the tint color of the navigation bar.

`self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.redColor`

If you want all navigation bars to have their `tintColor` set to a color, you can also use UIAppearance.

`UINavigationBar.appearance.tintColor = UIColor.redColor`

Comment: What if I had an instance of UIViewController such as:

screen_controller = UIViewController.alloc.initWithNibName(nil, bundle:nil)

and I wanted to change its default back button color before I display in on another controller?

UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.get_window.rootViewController.viewControllers[@controller].pushViewController(screen_controller, animated:true)

Comment: As long as you have access to the `UINavigationController` you can access it's `navigationBar` property and set it's `tintColor`. I'll also update my answer with a global solution too to apply to all bar button items in all nav bars.

Comment: Thanks FluffyJack! 

I just realized I have to declare UINavigationBar.appearance.tintColor = UIColor.redColor in parent controller to make it work.